# ¿Quién puede decirme que es este error en las funciones de Firebase?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, funciones

Estoy trabajando en el backend para una aplicación web y he seleccionado firebase para que maneje la infraestructura del proyecto.

Todo bien, la base de datos ya contiene toda la información, actualmente la aplicación web tiene todos los métodos implementados directamente en el código de la aplicación, y por motivos de analiticas y escabilidad, queremos manejar la interfaz de la aplicacion mediante solicitudes http (funciones) y para esto utilizo funciones en firebase.

El problema surge cuando intento obtener, por ejemplo, todos los documentos de una colección en el sdk.
Al deployar las funciones se implementan en firebase sin problema pero, al momento de enviar la solicitud, recibo el siguiente error:

Error: could not handle the request / Error: no se pudo manejar la solicitud.

La inquietud es que no tengo ningún problema en el código, todo se ejecuta correctamente, no entiendo de donde proviene el problema. Siempre espero de 1 a 5 minutos para poder hacer la solicitud y asegurarme que la funcion ya esta implementada en firebase y no surgan estos errores pero, esta vez, no sé de donde proviene.

El código es el siguiente y estoy usando el SDK de Firebase en Node.js. Más adelante voy a implementar express para manejar las rutas de las solicitudes pero, ese no es la prioridad ahora.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

exports.obtenerSignos = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('signos')
        .get()
        .then((query) => {
            let signos = [];
            query.forEach((doc) => {
                signos.push(doc.data());
            });
            return response.status(200).json(signos);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            response.status(500).json(error);
        })
})
```

El resultado de la solicitud deberia ser el arreglo con todos los documentos de la coleccion signos, que no es más que los signos del zodiaco y sus propiedades y caracteristicas.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, he estado buscando pero las soluciones que he encontrado no aplican en mi proyecto.

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Adjunto la direccion de la funcion para que obtengan más detalles de la solicitud.
https://us-central1-horoscopo-angelical.cloudfunctions.net/obtenerSignos

**Al ejecutar la funcion de manera local con firebase serve la función funciona correctamente, me muestra la información de los Signos**

¿A que se debe esto, cual será mi problema?

```
[{"nombre":"Cáncer","img":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/horoscopo-angelical.appspot.com/o/Cancer.svg?alt=media&token=eaf1a5ec-aece-423a-894b-7388e379518d","id":4,"introduccion":"En astrología, Cáncer es el cuarto signo del zodiaco, el segundo de naturaleza negativa y de cualidad cardinal. Pertenece junto a Escorpio y a Piscis al elemento agua. Está regido por la Luna. Su signo opuesto es Capricornio."},{"introduccion":"En astrología, Libra es el séptimo signo del zodiaco, el cuarto de naturaleza positiva y el tercero de cualidad cardinal. Pertenece junto a Géminis y Acuario al elemento aire. Está regido por Venus y su signo opuesto y complementario es Aries.","nombre":"Libra","img":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/horoscopo-angelical.appspot.com/o/Libra.svg?alt=media&token=f081b9de-7e04-40d9-998f-ea8aa9e36459","id":7},{"img":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/horoscopo-angelical.appspot.com/o/Virgo.svg?alt=media&token=1cc59bb8-163f-45e7-b214-c4280df9a47d","introduccion":"En astrología, Virgo es el sexto signo del zodiaco, el tercero de naturaleza negativa (femenina) y de cualidad mutable. Pertenece junto a Tauro y Capricornio al elemento Tierra. Está regido por Mercurio. Su signo opuesto y compatible es Piscis.","id":6,"nombre":"Virgo"},{"introduccion":"En astrología, Sagittarius o Sagitario es el noveno sigo del zodiaco y el primero de naturaleza positiva y de cualidad mutable. Pertenece junto a Aries y Leo al elemento fuego. Está regido por Júpiter. Su signo opuesto y complementario es Géminis.","nombre":"Sagitario","id":9,"img":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/horoscopo-angelical.appspot.com/o/Sagitario.svg?alt=media&token=31a41e86-1d44-4ceb-bc6c-6f7a1e36214d"},{"nombre":"Acuario","img":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/horoscopo-angelical.appspot.com/o/Acuario.svg?alt=media&token=5d1ae7a2-45dd-497a-abf4-10a34b3fc798","id":11,"introduccion":"En astrología, Aquiaros o Acuario es el undécimo signo del zódiaco, el sexto de naturaleza positiva y el cuarto de cualidad fija. Pertenece junto a Géminis y Libra al elemento aire. Su signo opuesto y complementario es Leo."},{"id":3,"introduccion":"En astrología, Gemini o Géminis es el tercer signo del zodiaco, el segundo de naturaleza positiva (masculina) y de cualidad mutable. Pertenece, junto a Libra y Acuario al elemento aire y está regido por Mercurio. Su signo opuesto es Sagitario.","nombre":"Géminis","img":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/horoscopo-angelical.appspot.com/o/Geminis.svg?alt=media&token=ce854f35-936c-494a-8d8e-3734dfd49106"},{"id":10,"nombre":"Capricornio","introduccion":"En astrología, Capricornius o Capricornio es el décimo signo del zodiaco, el quinto de naturaleza femenina y de cualidad cardinal. Pertenece junto a Tauro y Virgo al elemento tierra. Está regido por Saturno. Su sigo opuesto es Cáncer. ","img":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/horoscopo-angelical.appspot.com/o/Capricornio.svg?alt=media&token=05727a4e-78ff-45f3-9407-d3014f113a2a"},{"nombre":"Tauro","img":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/horoscopo-angelical.appspot.com/o/Tauro.svg?alt=media&token=10a7822a-a658-44d6-843f-6281e60e7d3c","introduccion":"En astrología, Tauro es el segundo signo del zodiaco y el primero de cualidad fija y negativa. Su signo puesto y complementario a la vez es Escorpio. Junto a los signos de Virgo y Capricornio, pertenece al elemento Tierra y es regido por el planeta Venus.","id":2},{"nombre":"Piscis","id":12,"img":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/horoscopo-angelical.appspot.com/o/Piscis.svg?alt=media&token=5c8c0954-fc4b-4cde-8ea8-7293e6ea8540","introduccion":"En astrología, Pisces o Piscis es el duodécimo signo del zódiaco, el sexto de naturaleza negativa (femenina) y de cualidad mutable. Pertenece, junto a Cáncer y Escorpio al elemento agua. Está regido por Neptuno y Júpiter. Su signo opuesto y compatible es Virgo."},{"introduccion":"En la astrología, Escorpio es el octavo signo del zodiaco, el cuarto de naturaleza negativa y el tercero de cualidad fija. Está regido por los planetas Marte y Plutón. Pertenece junto a Cáncer y Piscis, al elemento agua. Su signo opuesto y complementario a la vez es Tauro. ","img":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/horoscopo-angelical.appspot.com/o/Escorpio.svg?alt=media&token=936454ad-6d6a-4a9d-afde-1d605c687a1b","id":8,"nombre":"Escorpio"},{"introduccion":"En astrología, Aries es el primer signo del zodiaco, el primero de naturaleza positiva y de cualidad cardinal. Pertenece junto a Leo y Sagitario al elemento fuego. Está regido por el planeta Marte. Su signo opuesto y complementario es Libra.","img":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/horoscopo-angelical.appspot.com/o/Aries.svg?alt=media&token=6358a8cf-ada8-4ece-8642-d7842e4a3488","id":1,"nombre":"Aries"},{"img":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/horoscopo-angelical.appspot.com/o/Leo.svg?alt=media&token=4be5eb23-5c3a-4c80-8348-b2677774d38f","id":5,"nombre":"Leo","introduccion":"En astrología, Leo es el quinto signo del zodiaco, el tercer de naturaleza positiva y el segundo de cualidad fija. Pertenece junto a Aries y Sagitario al elemento fuego. Está regido por el Sol. Su signo opuesto y complementario es Acuario."}]
```

Comment: se puede deber a que no haz configurado correctamente permisos de `firebase` por lo tanto tu app de manera local si tiene acceso porque como tal `firebase` la esta autorizando, pero al momento de que cualquier otro origen que no sea tu app este intentando usar tu firebase seguramente se bloquee, son medidas de seguridad de firebase y debes configurarlas para que esto no ocurra.

Comment: Ese mensaje de error se ve cuando la Función termina con algún error. Puedes ver logs más detallados en la consola de GCP, checa ahí qué pasa, y si es necesario, agrega la información aquí para depurar.

Comment: Si era un error de la función, hay pude encontrar más detalles. Gracias.